# To find element by xPath on IE11. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, xpath

I learn JS two days, so i dont have many knowledge to resolve my problems and need help.
I need to get element by xPath like a

```
docHTML.evaluate(elementName, docHTML.body, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue
```

But problem is that i need use only IE 11. 
I know, that IE does not supported xPath, but i could find other way, using ActionXObject.

This idea i was find on [How do you run an xPath query in IE11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19300859/how-do-you-run-an-xpath-query-in-ie11) but i cant run this code.

I try

```
var doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM'); 
doc.loadXML(window.XMLDocument); 
var node = doc.selectSingleNode('//div');
alert(node);
```

but didn't succeed.

Maybe I’m not getting the XML document correctly or there’s no problem?

Comment: You can try to use the alternatives for xPath. For example, You can select an element by its ID or Selecting elements by the classes applied to them. Ref: https://hexfox.com/p/an-alternative-to-xpath-selectors/ and https://discuss.appium.io/t/alternative-for-using-find-by-xpath/12385

Comment: Unfortunatly in my case i must use only xPath. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will worked with a simple pages. On google.com he returned me result ~145.

```
xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("MSXML.DOMDocument");
var docHTML = window.document.documentElement;
var yourString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(docHTML);
xmlDoc.loadXML(yourString);
var node = xmlDoc.selectNodes('//div');
node.length
```

But on more dificult sites loadXML to drop down with false value.